# How to setup weblate to handle .net project with resx file

Tags: weblate

I'm trying to setup WebLate to support a project containing multiple resx files.

I was able to setup the first step by specifying the GitHub url of our project.
But after I need to setup a component and I don't understand this step.

Here is a screenshot (in french sorry)

[image]

Why do I have to choose a specific resx file ?
Should I be able to translate all the files ?

Also when I choose a specific file it doesn't work.
It complains at the next step when I have to setup the file mask.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

In Weblate you configure one translation file per component. You can automate this using  [component discovery addon](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/addons.html#addon-weblate-discovery-discovery).